# Range Limiting the result of a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

How do I Make a range of Cells to Zero If a calculation gives A Negative Number?

Example: =D12-D19

Answer: -1

I would like to replace the negative to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More efficiently, you could use:

```
=MAX(0, SUM(A1:A5))
```

Comment: How do i incorporate this formula into =IF(AND($H$14<F22,F22<=($H$14+$H$15)),$I$15,IF(AND($H$14+$H$15<F22,F22<=($H$14+$H$15+$H$16)),$I$16,IF(AND($H$14+$H$15+$H$16<F22,F22<=($H$14+$H$15+$H$16+$H$17)),$I$17,$I$14)))                  It keeps running a circular reference error. Help!

Comment: The value am checking against is 150

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A5) < 0, 0, SUM(A1:A5))
```

or depending on your locale:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A5) < 0; 0; SUM(A1:A5))
```

which means:

```
IF the sum of the cells A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 is less than 0
  make it 0
ELSE
  make it the sum of the cells A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5
```

Comment: @Bart, can i ask you another question,

Comment: @Bart, can i ask you another question,

Comment: @Bart, i managed to use the above formula and it works. The next issue is when this cell value is 0, i have to stop the purchase of another cell and set that cell to 0. I tried the similar approach, but i get circular reference error.

Comment: @dwayne, perhaps you'd like to create another question for that.